# Use a value in a feature file in a cucumber test?

Tags: java, cucumber, feature-file

Is there any way to declare a variable in a feature file to then use in a cucumber test?  Something like this:

myFile.feature

```
Given whenever a value is 50
```

myFile.java

```
@Given("^whenever a value is 50$")
public void testing(value) {
    assertEqual(value, 50);
}
```

Honestly, I don't even know what this would look like.  But I would love to not have to declare a value in both the feature file AND the Cucumber test.  Thanks!

Comment: Why would you want to do this. Give a better example and maybe someone can give a better answer.

Comment: kroe761 You should accept David Baak's answer, it is the right one.  @diabolist Seriously?  It is done **all the time**.

Comment: @MikeJRamsey56 so you think David Baak's answer, answers the question! I suspected OP was after something else, that answer is just too obvious, and has nothing to do with 'declaring a variable in a feature file'.  Anyhow we'll never know for sure unless OP comes back and clarifies

Comment: @diabolist I just reread the question and all I can conclude is that kroe761's question **is** that obvious.  Someone who is so new to cucumber that he is unaware of its parameter passing features (no pun intended). I can see now that you were looking for a deeper question. Pronouns like *this* are open to interpretation.  I didn't understand what you meant. I do now. :-)

Comment: Well, this was interesting.  I have just accepted the answer, and yes, I was just that new/dumb in Cucumber.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can! Write the Given-step in the feature.

```
Feature: foobar

Scenario: something
    Given whenever a value is 50
```

Then run it as a JUnit test. You will see something like this in the console.

```
@Given("^whenever a value is (\\d+)$")
public void whenever_a_value_is(int arg1) throws Throwable {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new PendingException();
}
```

Then you can copy+paste it and change it to:

```
@Given("^whenever a value is (\\d+)$")
public void whenever_a_value_is(int value) {
    assertEquals(value, 50);
}
```